# Have to create desired output from arrays

Tags: python

I have three arrays from scraping, and now I need to print this output column-wise in a CSV file using the `numpy`, `pandas` or `csv` library.

---

The output is looks like this:

```
['Apple iPhone 11 (Black, 64 GB)', 'Apple iPhone 11 (Black, 128 GB)', 'Apple iPhone 11 (White, 128 GB)', 'Apple iPhone 11 (White, 64 GB)', 'Apple 
iPhone 11 (Green, 128 GB)', 'Apple iPhone 11 (Purple, 128 GB)', 'Apple iPhone 11 (Red, 128 GB)', 'Apple iPhone 11 (Purple, 64 GB)', 'Apple iPhone 
11 (Red, 64 GB)', 'Apple iPhone 11 (Yellow, 128 GB)', 'Apple iPhone 11 (Yellow, 64 GB)', 'Apple iPhone 11 (Green, 64 GB)', 'Apple iPhone 11 (Black, 256 GB)', 'Apple iPhone 11 (White, 256 GB)', 'Apple iPhone 11 (Red, 256 GB)', 'Apple iPhone 11 (Yellow, 256 GB)', 'Apple iPhone 11 (Green, 256 GB)', 'Apple iPhone 11 (Purple, 256 GB)', 'Apple iPhone 11 Pro Max (Silver, 256 GB)', 'Apple iPhone 11 Pro (Midnight Green, 64 GB)', 'Apple iPhone 
11 Pro (Gold, 64 GB)', 'Apple iPhone 11 Pro (Silver, 64 GB)', 'Apple iPhone 11 Pro (Space Grey, 256 GB)', 'Apple iPhone 11 Pro Max (Gold, 64 GB)']
['₹68,300', '₹73,600', '₹73,600', '₹68,300', '₹73,600', '₹73,600', '₹73,600', '₹68,300', '₹68,300', '₹73,600', '₹68,300', '₹68,300', '₹84,100', '₹84,100', '₹84,100', '₹84,100', '₹84,100', '₹84,100', '₹1,31,900', '₹1,06,600', '₹1,06,600', '₹1,06,600', '₹1,21,300', '₹1,17,100']
['4.7', '4.7', '4.7', '4.7', '4.7', '4.7', '4.7', '4.7', '4.7', '4.7', '4.7', '4.7', '4.7', '4.7', '4.7', '4.7', '4.7', '4.7', '4.7', '4.7', '4.7', '4.7', '4.7', '4.7']
```

Comment: Please first checkout how to write a post on stackoverflow. For instance you could have formated your output as code, this could improve the readability for the community. However, pandas has the command `pandas.to_csv()`. Within this command you can specify your wanted headers. Check it out here https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html

Comment: Please ask proper question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(data).transpose()
df.to_csv('filename.csv', index=False)
```

Output:

```
                                              0          1    2
0                Apple iPhone 11 (Black, 64 GB)    ₹68,300  4.7
1               Apple iPhone 11 (Black, 128 GB)    ₹73,600  4.7
2               Apple iPhone 11 (White, 128 GB)    ₹73,600  4.7
3                Apple iPhone 11 (White, 64 GB)    ₹68,300  4.7
4               Apple iPhone 11 (Green, 128 GB)    ₹73,600  4.7
5              Apple iPhone 11 (Purple, 128 GB)    ₹73,600  4.7
6                 Apple iPhone 11 (Red, 128 GB)    ₹73,600  4.7
7               Apple iPhone 11 (Purple, 64 GB)    ₹68,300  4.7
8                  Apple iPhone 11 (Red, 64 GB)    ₹68,300  4.7
9              Apple iPhone 11 (Yellow, 128 GB)    ₹73,600  4.7
10              Apple iPhone 11 (Yellow, 64 GB)    ₹68,300  4.7
11               Apple iPhone 11 (Green, 64 GB)    ₹68,300  4.7
12              Apple iPhone 11 (Black, 256 GB)    ₹84,100  4.7
13              Apple iPhone 11 (White, 256 GB)    ₹84,100  4.7
14                Apple iPhone 11 (Red, 256 GB)    ₹84,100  4.7
15             Apple iPhone 11 (Yellow, 256 GB)    ₹84,100  4.7
16              Apple iPhone 11 (Green, 256 GB)    ₹84,100  4.7
17             Apple iPhone 11 (Purple, 256 GB)    ₹84,100  4.7
18     Apple iPhone 11 Pro Max (Silver, 256 GB)  ₹1,31,900  4.7
19  Apple iPhone 11 Pro (Midnight Green, 64 GB)  ₹1,06,600  4.7
20            Apple iPhone 11 Pro (Gold, 64 GB)  ₹1,06,600  4.7
21          Apple iPhone 11 Pro (Silver, 64 GB)  ₹1,06,600  4.7
22     Apple iPhone 11 Pro (Space Grey, 256 GB)  ₹1,21,300  4.7
23        Apple iPhone 11 Pro Max (Gold, 64 GB)  ₹1,17,100  4.7
```

Answer (score 0):

just create 3 seperate list and append to each list data while **scraping**. Once this is done you can merge all the 3 list as dataframe and finally save the file as csv.

For instance:-
1)Create 3 empty list

```
brand=[]
price=[]
rating=[]
```

2. append data to the individual list while scraping
3. create a dataframe from list

   ```
   df= pd.DataFrame({
               'brand':brand,
               'price':price,
               'rating':rating})
   ```

4)Save to csv

Comment: thanks!!! its done... also send code for numpy library

Comment: If the above code helped you in solving the issue, could you please accept the answer....

Answer (score 0):

1)importing panda library

```
import pandas as pd
```

2)Our list

```
name = ['Apple iPhone 11 (Black, 64 GB)', 'Apple iPhone 11 (Black, 128 GB)', 'Apple iPhone 11 (White, 128 GB)', 'Apple iPhone 11 (White, 64 GB)', 'Apple iPhone 11 (Green, 128 GB)', 'Apple iPhone 11 (Purple, 128 GB)', 'Apple iPhone 11 (Red, 128 GB)', 'Apple iPhone 11 (Purple, 64 GB)', 'Apple iPhone 11 (Red, 64 GB)', 'Apple iPhone 11 (Yellow, 128 GB)', 'Apple iPhone 11 (Yellow, 64 GB)', 'Apple iPhone 11 (Green, 64 GB)', 'Apple iPhone 11 (Black, 256 GB)', 'Apple iPhone 11 (White, 256 GB)', 'Apple iPhone 11 (Red, 256 GB)', 'Apple iPhone 11 (Yellow, 256 GB)', 'Apple iPhone 11 (Green, 256 GB)', 'Apple iPhone 11 (Purple, 256 GB)', 'Apple iPhone 11 Pro Max (Silver, 256 GB)', 'Apple iPhone 11 Pro (Midnight Green, 64 GB)', 'Apple iPhone 11 Pro (Gold, 64 GB)', 'Apple iPhone 11 Pro (Silver, 64 GB)', 'Apple iPhone 11 Pro (Space Grey, 256 GB)', 'Apple iPhone 11 Pro Max (Gold, 64 GB)']
price = ['₹68,300', '₹73,600', '₹73,600', '₹68,300', '₹73,600', '₹73,600', '₹73,600', '₹68,300', '₹68,300', '₹73,600', '₹68,300', '₹68,300', '₹84,100', '₹84,100', '₹84,100', '₹84,100', '₹84,100', '₹84,100', '₹1,31,900', '₹1,06,600', '₹1,06,600', '₹1,06,600', '₹1,21,300', '₹1,17,100'] 
ratings = ['4.7', '4.7', '4.7', '4.7', '4.7', '4.7', '4.7', '4.7', '4.7', '4.7', '4.7', '4.7', '4.7', '4.7', '4.7', '4.7', '4.7', '4.7', '4.7', '4.7', '4.7', '4.7', '4.7', '4.7']
```

3)Getting lists into dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(name,price,ratings)),columns = ['Name','Price','Rating']) 

df.T # to get name, price and rating in column vise
```

4)Save to CSV File

```
df.T.to_csv('file_name')
```